# How to add SEO properties in sitemap using xml

Tags: html, xml, sitemap

I am using xml sitemap with basic 4 component
like below

```
<url>

<loc>http://xyz.in/</loc>

<lastmod>2017-05-16T08:45:55+00:00</lastmod>

<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>

</url>
```

I want to add SEO property in this list.please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "SEO property"?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? Are you trying to programmatically add this "property" (do you mean attribute?)? What programming language are you using? What XML library are you using? What output do you want?

Comment: Are you trying to ask "What changes can I make to my sitemap to improve my SEO?"? If so, you're off-topic as it is outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am confuse please Tell me The sitemap and  SEO are diffent thing or same and i want to add sitemap.xml file in my website please help me.

Comment: "The sitemap and SEO are diffent thing" — Yes. Do some basic research.

Comment: " i want to add sitemap.xml file in my website please help me" — We can't. We know nothing about how your server is configured.

Answer (score -2):

There are no additional properties you can add to your sitemap to help improve SEO. You may have read about sitemaps and SEO before, having a sitemap is good for SEO, but the layout of them is very straight forward and you've nailed it.

If your sitemap is incredibly large you might want to consider splitting it up, so that search engines can tackle the parsing in chunks.

Comment: I am fresher and I work on website and I simply create sitemap.xml but client Requirement is add propery of SEO. What Should I do or my output is right or wrong